# How are we supposed to derive formula for magnetic field density?

Tags: magnetic-fields

The formula for magnetic field density is B^2/2mu. How to prove it?

Comment: I suppose you mean the *energy density* of the magnetic field. Duplicate of this question: [Magnetostatic energy density — derivation without introducing inductance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57236/157014), perhaps.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the linked question?